# visual studio code + ubuntu + chinese nameShort

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I

1. set nameShort to Chinese
2. build deb
3. install deb on ubuntu 20.04.2

then it will appear garbled on Ubuntu。 Like the screenshots

[image: in file]

[image: in ubuntu]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkDcb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C7Vu.jpg)

Comment: have you install the language package? `sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-zh-hans-base`

Comment: yes,  installed.  I added two images，The list of applications is correct，Only the tooltip is garbled